# Missing entries MySQL

Tags: mysql

here is my MySQL code.

It's working and show's only the `email` with an associated `clients.ID`

but I have `email` with no `clients.ID` and those are not shown.

How can I correct that.

Thanks

```
SELECT 
  origins_outmail.ID AS mailid, 
  clients.ID AS cliid, 
  origins_outmail.asmailid, 
  origins_outmail.email, 
  clients.email, 
  origins_outmail.date, 
  origins_outmail.content 
FROM origins_outmail 
JOIN clients ON clients.email = origins_outmail.email 
ORDER BY origins_outmail.date DESC
```

Comment: If the emails with no language id are in only one of the tables, not both, use LEFT JOIN and put that table at the left (first).

Comment: there's no php or mysqli here. I have removed those tags. You can put them back in once you've shown us relevance.

Comment: "use LEFT JOIN and put that table at the left (first)"  MySQL also supports `RIGHT JOiN` which basically does the same thing but "reversed" to so the topicstarter does not have to change the table order.

Answer (score 2):

Since Left join seems the answer here so I am rewriting the query using Left join -

```
SELECT origins_outmail.ID AS mailid
      ,clients.ID AS cliid
      ,origins_outmail.asmailid
      ,origins_outmail.email
      ,clients.email
      ,origins_outmail.date
      ,origins_outmail.content 
FROM origins_outmail 
LEFT JOIN clients ON clients.email = origins_outmail.email 
ORDER BY origins_outmail.date DESC
```

Comment: HGroupe, if this answer solves your problem, be sure to click "Accept".